# Populating jquery autocomplete with data from asp WebMethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a WebMethod in my asp.net page that returns a string that is the representation of a JSON array containing data that i want to use as source for my jquery-ui autocomplete textbox.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCities(string cityName)
{
    JArray json = new JArray(
        new JObject(new JProperty("label", "label1"), new JProperty("category", "cat1"), new JProperty("value", "v1")),
        new JObject(new JProperty("label", "label2"), new JProperty("category", "cat1"), new JProperty("value", "v2")),
        new JObject(new JProperty("label", "label3"), new JProperty("category", "cat2"), new JProperty("value", "v3")),
        new JObject(new JProperty("label", "label4"), new JProperty("category", "cat3"), new JProperty("value", "v4")));
    return json.ToString();
}
```

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtCity").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var param = { cityName: $('#txtCity').val() };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetCities",
                    data: JSON.stringify(param),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d); //here data.d contains the json array string
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#output" ).val( ui.item.value );
                return false;
            },
            minLength: 2//minLength as 2, it means when ever user enter 2 character in TextBox the AutoComplete method will fire and get its source data. 
        });
    });
</script>
```

But my autocomplete generates an item for each character in the JSON string. I assume I'm not returning it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

```
success: function (data) {
                        response($.parseJSON(data.d))
                    },
```

Had to parse the JSON.